# Java doesn't print every result from SQL-Database

Tags: java, sqlite

Following problem: I am just starting with programming and just begun translating a python programm to Java. I have problems with the following method "getCurrentRoom()":

```
static void getCurrentRoom(){

        try{
                Statement stmt = Database.connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT roomid, roomname, roomdesc, from_id, direction, route_desc FROM user, rooms, route WHERE user.location = rooms.roomid AND route.from_id = rooms.roomid");

                while (rs.next()){    
                //1st while loop 
                    String roomname = rs.getString("roomname");
                    String roomdesc = rs.getString("roomdesc");
                    int roomid = rs.getInt("roomid");


                    if (userLocation == roomid){
                            System.out.println("\n" + roomname);
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            System.out.println("\n" + roomdesc);
                            Thread.sleep(1000);

                                 while (rs.next()){
                                 //2nd while loop
                                    String route_desc = rs.getString("route_desc");
                                    int from_id = rs.getInt("from_id");

                                        if (roomid == from_id){
                                            System.out.println("\n" + route_desc);  
                                        //not enough printet here 
                                        }
                                 }
                    }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

In the first "while-loop" I want to check which roomid corresponds to the userLocation which is defined earlier in another method. This works just fine and I get the right result printed (note that there only is one result that needs to be returned).

In the second "while-loop" however when I try to print out the route descriptions which fit the roomid there are only 2 results returned although there are 3 fitting results in the Database.

The  relevant database tables used in the code above look like this:

```
rooms(roomid, roomdesc, roomname)
```

with "roomid" as primany key

```
user(userid, name, score, location, health, strenght, userdesc, moves)
```

with "userid" as primany key

```
route(route_id, from_id, to_id, direction, route_desc
```

with "route_id" as primany key

I can't find where I went wrong so any help would be highly appreciated.

Sincerily AlexanderZC

Comment: It's a bad idea to mingle I/O and database code like this.  I'd recommend writing and testing the database code on its own.

Comment: `rs.next()` advances the ResultSet to next database row. So, for one row in outer loop, the inner while loop will expend all the remaining records. is that what you want?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I really didnt realize that. Thank you so much, fixed it by getting a seperate ResultSet.

Comment: A different resultset, but you only have one query ? These loops are not what you want. Just remove the inner loop and print the line in the `if` (but you will have you sleep here...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment, you read the line, let say the row 2 is the one you want.

```
ResultSet.index = 1
```

The condition is true, so you read the inner while condition `while(rs.next())`

```
ResultSet.index = 2
```

You skip the row at index 1. So you never prints the seconds row (where index = 1)

If you really need to write this like that. You should use a do-while to run the code on the current row (the one you use in the `if (userLocation == roomid)`) then check if there is still more rows to read.

```
while (rs.next()){    
                ...    
                    if (userLocation == roomid){
                           ...    
                                 do{
                                 ...
                                 } while (rs.next());
                    }
```

This would not move forward before reading the correct line.

EDIT :

Of course, you could update the query to filter the result set based on the `userLocation` using a `PreparedStatement`. That way, you only get the rows you need.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is because the first `rs.next()` is advancing your pointer and you only have two more elements to traverse.
Try putting `rs.beforeFirst()` before your second while-loop.

Comment: The resultset start at -1, so calling `next()` will put you on the first row.

Comment: @AxelH That is correct, so initially the cursor is before the first row, when calling `next()` it is put in the first row. The problem that AlexanderZC is explaining is that the second while-loop is only showing 2 out of 3 rows, and that is because the  second while is doing a `next()` again, putting the cursor on the second row.

Comment: I agree with that, but I didn't understand that with you answer ;)